Re film title, "Kinds of Kindness"
Ever since I've heard the title Kinds of Kindness it's been bouncing around my head.
I'm curious whether a technical term exists for linking two words with homonymic stems, as occurs here.
My surface level research tells me this is either a case of polysemy or nondescript wordplay.
Any help is appreciated!

Probably polyptoton - see this question

This question is similar to: Is it still diacope if the words have different inflections?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. But the answer is certainly polyptoton.
